# Postfix SASL error: warning: unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, sasl

My use case is to use my own mail server to send emails from CCTV NVRs to overcome the daily limits imposed by GMail. The NVR has an option to setup authentication. The config worked for whitelisted IP but I don't have a static IP. So, I set up the postfix server with SASL authentication. Everytime I get warning: unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure

Here are the configuration files:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
mydomain = sample.com
myorigin = $mydomain
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 3.6

smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = some_value

mydestination = $myhostname, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

**/usr/lib/sasl2/smtpd.conf**

```
pwcheck_method: auxprop
auxprop_plugin: sasldb
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
```

**/etc/default/saslauthd** (modified)

```
# Example: MECHANISMS="pam"
MECHANISMS="sasldb"
```

**/etc/postfix/master.cf**: No changes made

I'm able to list the users using sasldblistusers2. In the saslauthd.service, I can see only this log. No indication that the postfix is calling this for authentication:

```
saslauthd[76548]:                 : listening on socket: /var/run/saslauthd/mux
```